# Python: Create File Directories based on Dictionary Key names

Tags: python

I wonder if there is a way to turn a dictionary into a directory structure. For a example a dictionary with following keys:

```
dict['dir1']['subdir1']['subsubdir']['folder1']
            ['subdir2']['subsubdir']['folder1']['folder2']['folder3']
            ['subdir3']['subsubdir']
```

would result to a three directories (where each subdirectory correspond to dictionary key name:

```
/dir1/subdir1/subsubdir/folder1/
/dir1/subdir2/subsubdir/folder1/folder2/folder3/
/dir1/subdir3/subsubdir/
```

Comment: In Python, the keys of a dictionary are non-ordered.

Comment: @Adam, directories aren't ordered.

Comment: Could you take advantage of `mydict.items()`?

Comment: @MattBryant I believe I'm confused then. Couldn't the OP just call the dictionary as so: `myDirectory = dict['dir1'] + '/' + dict['subdir1'] + '/' + dict['subsubdir'] + '/' + dict['folder1'] + '/'` ?

Comment: How do you maintain the breakpoint or is it fixed like 3,5, and 2 keys?

Comment: I can sum all the directories together like so: myDirectory = dict['dir1'] + '/' + dict['subdir1'] + '/' + dict['subsubdir'] + '/'........ But it is not known how many nested sub-keys each key has..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os
import os.path

def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)
d = tree()

d["dir1"]["subdir1"]["subsubdir"]["folder1"]
d["dir1"]["subdir2"]["subsubdir"]["folder1"]["folder2"]["folder3"]
d["dir1"]["subdir3"]["subsubdir"]

def rec(directory, current_path):
    if len(directory):
        for direc in directory:
            rec(directory[direc], os.path.join(current_path, direc))
    else:
        os.makedirs(current_path)

rec(d, "")
```

**Output**

```
~/Desktop$ tree dir1
dir1
|-- subdir1
|   `-- subsubdir
|       `-- folder1
|-- subdir2
|   `-- subsubdir
|       `-- folder1
|           `-- folder2
|               `-- folder3
`-- subdir3
    `-- subsubdir

10 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Does 'root = lambda: defaultdict(root)' import some new func()s taken from defaultdict into a local namespace?

Comment: @Sputnix Actually thats a classic trick, to create a tree like structure. Nope, it will not import any other functions.

Comment: root() gives NameError if it's not improted

Comment: @Sputnix `root = lambda: defaultdict(root)` is not importing, we are defining `root` with that and that is necessary :)

Comment: Seems like: print dir(locals()['root'])

Comment: @Sputnix Actually, we can write it like the way I have updated my answer now. Please check

Comment: Yeah, because with labmda you loose a track: 'root': <function <lambda> at 0x10049aed8>

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty simple with a quick recursive function:

```
nested = {'folderA': {'sub1': None, 'sub2': {'subsub1': None}},
          'folderB': {'sub1': None}}

def make_dirs_from_dict(d, current_dir='./'):
    for key, val in d.items():
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(current_dir, key))
        if type(val) == dict:
            make_dirs_from_dict(val, os.path.join(current_dir, key))

make_dirs_from_dict(nested)
```

This solution stops whenever it hits a non-dict value, although you could adapt it so that the end-points are (potentially empty) lists.

Result:

```
C:\Users\me\dirplay>tree
start_dir.
├───folderA
│   ├───sub1
│   └───sub2
│       └───subsub1
└───folderB
    └───sub1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally following your syntax, but you could use a list of tuples,

```
import os   
dirs = [(dir1,dir2,dir3), (dir1,dir2,dir4,dir5),...]
    for dir in dirs:
         loc = os.path.join(*dir)
         if not os.path.exists(loc):
               os.makedirs(loc)
```

May need some tweaking, but that should do it.